# C program to create a square pattern with two triangles

Tags: c, for-loop

So, the output should come out with a incrementing triangle of looped numbers (1,2,3,...) combined with a decrementing triangle of stars. Like this:

```
1********
12*******
123******
1234*****
12345****
123456***
1234567**
12345678*
123456789
```

So far I have this but just can't figure out how to decrement the stars.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=1; i<=9; i++)
    {
        for (j=1; j<=i; j++)
        {
            printf ("%d",j);
        }

        int k;
        for(k=8; k>0; k--) {
            printf("*");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

And it prints out this:

```
1*******
12*******
123*******
1234*******
12345*******
123456*******
1234567*******
12345678*******
123456789*******
```

Comment: Think: how many stars do you need on each line? Hint: the total number of characters is 9.

Comment: Please be more careful with your indenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

- For k in 8 down to 0 (exclusive),

  - Print `*`.

This always prints 8 stars, but you want 9-i of them.

- For k in i+1 to 9 (inclusive),

  - Print `*`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that all you need to do is subtract the amount of numbers printed per line from the expected (in this case) 9 expected characters. `for(k=9 - i; k>0; k--)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=1; i<=9; i++){
        for (j=1; j<=i; j++){
            printf ("%d",j);
        }
        int k;
        for(k=9 - i; k>0; k--) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
1********
12*******
123******
1234*****
12345****
123456***
1234567**
12345678*
123456789
```

Comment: Or instead of `k`, just `for (; j<=9; j++)`

Comment: @ikegami He was 2 characters off, not really doing a whole complicated assignment, but fair enough, explanation for those two characters added.

Comment: @WeatherVane I like that, but I was hoping it would be clearer what is going on with the more explicit and close to his example styling.

Comment: Ok but mine is "the rest of the line".

Answer (score 0):

`printf` has the built in ability to print only limited portions of a string.
That comes in EXTREMELY handy for problems like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int i=9;
    while(i --> 0)
    {
        printf("%.*s%.*s\n", 9-i, "123456789", i, "********");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
1********
12*******
123******
1234*****
12345****
123456***
1234567**
12345678*
123456789
```

[IDE Link](https://ideone.com/vL7E8t)

Answer (score 0):

Begin with a mutable string of 9 stars. Then, replace one character at a time as you loop 9 times (ie: once for each row of output.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
    char stars[] = "*********";

    for( int i = 1; i <= 9; i++ ) {
        stars[i] = (char)(i + '0');
        puts( stars );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 3 loops.

1. The outer most loop (i) keep track of line number
2. First inner loop (j) will print the digits in sequence equal to number of lines
3. Second Inner loop (k) will print *, such that number of * printed are total lines - line number i.e. (9-i)

https://godbolt.org/z/e65def4P5

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for(int i=1; i<=9; i++)
    {
        for (int j=1; j<=i; j++)
        {
            printf ("%d",j);
        }
        for(int k=1; k<=9-i; k++) {
            printf("*");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```